# as3 {} vs new Object

Tags: actionscript-3, instantiation

What's the differences, pros, or cons of

```
var obj = {};
```

VS

```
var obj = new Object();
```

All I know is that the second example takes longer. Is there any real benefit?

** EDIT **

```
function loop() {
    var start = (new Date()).getTime();
    for(var i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
        //var b = {}; // takes ~548ms on my machine
        var b = new Object(); // takes ~287ms on my machine
    }
    trace((new Date()).getTime() - start);
    setTimeout(loop, 1);
}
loop();
```

If you switch between `var b = {};` and `var b = new Object();` You'll see the performance differences. They are opposite from my recollection and what I mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, they are equivalent.  By "the second example takes longer", I assume you mean only in time to type the statement, and maybe a probably immeasurable amount of time to evaluate - but the execution time should be equivalent.

Comment: Your answer provoked me to re-run speed tests. My findings are posted in an EDIT to my question.

Comment: I would re-run your test several times over, something like 25 times for each variation - in completely new processes - then use a spreadsheet to track and calculate the averages.  (Just don't want to make sure you're not running into some of the common myths around micro-benchmarks.)

Answer (score 3):

Some testing tells me that `new Object()` is a fair percentage quicker, though this is only in comparison to the `{}` syntax, not to the abundance of any other tasks you might want to do.

The testing function:

```
function time(amount:int, test:Function):Number
{
    var average:Number = 0;
    var averages:Array = [];

    for(var n:int = 0; n<amount; n++)
    {
        var start:Number = getTimer();

        test();

        averages[averages.length] = getTimer() - start;
    }

    for each(var a:Number in averages) average += a;

    return average / averages.length;
}
```

Then our two test subjects:

```
function short():void
{
    for(var i:int = 0; i<1000000; i++) var obj:Object = {};
}

function long():void
{
    for(var i:int = 0; i<1000000; i++) var obj:Object = new Object();
}
```

And the results:

```
trace(time(5, short));  // 278.6
trace(time(5, long));   // 153.6
```

There's roughly a 45% speed increase using `new Object()`, but you'll notice that the total time is still unnoticeable (even for 1,000,000 iterations).

Personally I'm still going to stick to the `{}` syntax for simplicity and tidiness amongst other personal preference reasons.